# Getting deployment time error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager after JBOSS EAP Version Upgrade from 6.4 to 7.4

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am trying to migrate my application server (JBOSS EAP) from 6.4 to 7.4.3. But, after migration I am getting the below error during my spring boot microservice deployment time.

**Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager**

Thus, after doing some research I have removed couple of essential tomcat dependencies(tomcat-embed-el-9.0.58 and tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58 from my maven pom and the deployment time issue has resolved. Now, I can deploy my application in my new local JBOSS EAP 7.4.3 server. But, the above mentioned two dependencies are essential and we can't exclude that as per our upper environment configuration.

Could you please give me some solutions except the above one(means without removing the tomcat dependencies) if you have faced this issue before. Thank you all!

Regards,
Ritesh

Answer (score 1):

EAP 7.4 is using Undertow and not Tomcat so Tomcat classes aren't available.
also it is really a bad practice to depend on spec implementations internal in your code. The fix would be to remove all usage of that Tomcat class or make it part of your application.

Comment: Hi @ehsavoie, I can deploy my application in my local app server(JBOSS EAP 7.4.3) after removing tomcat dependencies. But we are using Red Hat OpenShift for our upper environment deployment purpose. Red Hat OpenShift has different configuration compared to local JBOSS and Tomcat dependencies are essential for OpenShift deployment. Could you please tell me any other approach to deploy the application successfully in OpenShift environment(without removing tomcat components).

Comment: I'm no Openshift expert but I don't see how OpenShift might impact your code requiring you to use Tomcat's internationalization helper class. You can customize the configuration on OpenShift to match your needs.

Comment: Hi @ehsavoie, Thank you! Eventually I have found out the root cause. Actually hibernate validator component is trying to access javax-el-ELManager through javax bean validation. This is causing runtime issue with openshift as well as with the older JBOSS 6.4. We need to give tomcat embed el for the expression language support required by hibernate bean validation during runtime. As per our project specific recommendations we can use atleast hibernate validator 6.x version. Hibernate Validator 6.x supports Bean Validation 2.0 (JSR 380)/EL 3.0 which is causing the issue in older jboss/openshift.

Comment: One more thing I have got some solutions over the internet to downgrade the hibernate validator version. As I have told you as per our project specific recommendations we can't incorporate this. If you have some idea, could you please shed some lights on this. Thanks!